# Не удалось окрыть редактор из за непредвиденной ошибки:Не удалось считать файл python3.10.exe

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

помогите мне,я учюсь создавать виртуальное окружение на Visual Studio Code,для телеграм бота с помощью команды pipenv shell.И вот вроде все получилось(по видео уроку)но (PS C:\Users\Коваль> & C:/Users/Коваль/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/Users/Коваль/Desktop/Both_liver/main.py) Visual Studio выдает эту хрень,я соответственно прерхожу по ссылке и показывает ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы пытаетесь открыть исполняемый файл питона?

Comment: Просто перехожу по ссылке в терминале(перед этим [pip install pipenv,потом pipenv shell],затем ctrl+shift+p(выбираю подходящий питон)запускаю терминал и,выдает ссылку с ошибкой,хотя должен создаться файл .ехе(по идее)

Comment: Первое: вы используете прямые слешы  вместо обратных в пути

Comment: Второе: было бы здорово если бы вы уточнили где начинается и заканчивается promt(приветственная строка в консоли), а где начинается сама команда. В идеале нужно указывать команду без promt'а чтобы мы не гадали лишний раз

Comment: Третье: вы на экране видите абсолютно закономерный итог перехода по пути до исполняемого файла. Какую операцию или задачу вы планировали выполнить  переходя по данной ссылке?